# Introducir mapa de Google con gvNix

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

Me gustaría saber qué debo tener en cuenta si quiero incluir como base un mapa de Google en mi proyecto.

Por lo que entiendo al ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
web mvc geo controller --class ~.web.MapController --preferredMapping map
```

El geoportal base incluye por defecto una capa con la cartografía de "Open Street Maps", quisiera que ese mapa sea Google Streets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente no está soportada este tipo de capa en gvNIX.

Si que existe un plugin de leaflet que te permite añadirlo ([en este post](http://mappinggis.com/2013/10/como-incluir-las-capas-de-google-en-leaflet/) te explican como hacerlo para una página con leaflet suelto), pero si lo incluyes en tu mapa generado con gvNIX tendrás que hacerlo a mano (usando JavaScript) y no estará integrado con las herramientas que aporta gvNIX (como la gestión en el TOC).

Para integrarlo habría que generar un nuevo tipo de capa gvNIX. Esto es posible hacerlo pero no es demasiado sencillo. Los pasos serían:

- Generar un nuevo `.tagx` para gestionarlo basado en el de Tile, por ejemplo.
- Generar la clase javaScript Layer registrada dentro del objeto `GvNIX_Map_Leaflet.LAYERS` (ejemplo de [capa Tile](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/scripts/leaflet/leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js#L3760)) en un nuevo fichero `.js`
- Registrar el nuevo `.js` en el fichero `load-scripts.tagx`
- usar el nuevo tag dentro de la página `.jspx` de la página.

Dependiendo de tus conocimientos en todo esto (JavaScript, jsp) te puede ser un poco complejo o muy dificil.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, entonces voy a estar investigando un poco mas. Tengo otra consulta aparte. Hay un tag que se agrega al mapa para que las capas vayan quedando opacas **<geo:toc-toolbar id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_toc_toolbar"
    z="user-managed">
    <tool:opacity id="opacity_slider" z="user-managed" />
   </geo:toc-toolbar>**. Las capas WMS que agregue a mi mapa base no toman ésta propiedad, por que?

Comment: Mejor crea otra consulta. Eso facilitará que otra persona pueda encontrar la respuesta a una pregunta como la tuya. Gracias.